# Adding a listener to a variable in Java/JavaFX which gets called on variable change

Tags: java, javafx, actionlistener

I know that there are listeners in JavaFX, and i'm sure Java. But I'm confused as how to implement them.

I have a boolean variable that is changed throughout my program. Everytime the boolean is changed, I want a function myFunc() to be ran.

Can this be done easily?

Comment: Could you show us some code? I don't think what you're asking is possible but the same effect can be accomplished in a different way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As simple as this:

```
public void changeBooleanFlag(boolean bEnabled)
{
    if(booleanFlag == bEnabled) return;
    booleanFlag = bEnabled;
    myFunc();
}
```

and whenever you want to change the boolean flag, you ***should*** do it via this method.

Comment: If you use this answer's solution, and if you are accessing this procedure from multiple threads, you definitely want to implement some synchronization mechanism.

Answer (score 26):

If you are using JavaFX 2 then it provides an out-of-box solutions for both JavaBeans component architecture and Observer design pattern. Moreover it gives a great flexibility of associating the state of variables by the property bindings. The code below illustrates the property changed events and the binding of property variables. Of course you can wrap the property accessors to hide details by like `getFlag()` and `setFlag()` below, and use them in the rest of application.

```
public class Demo extends Application {

    private BooleanProperty booleanProperty = new SimpleBooleanProperty(true);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        // Add change listener
        booleanProperty.addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {
                System.out.println("changed " + oldValue + "->" + newValue);
                myFunc();
            }
        });

        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Toggle boolean flag");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                booleanProperty.set(!booleanProperty.get()); //toggle
                System.out.println("toggled to " + booleanProperty.get());
            }
        });

        // Bind to another property variable
        btn.underlineProperty().bind(booleanProperty);

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public boolean getFlag() {
        return booleanProperty.get();
    }

    public void setFlag(boolean val) {
        booleanProperty.set(val);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I would do it using [PropertyChangeListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeListener.html). Here is a nice tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/propertychangelistener.html

Example of code:

```
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MyClass {
    private final List<PropertyChangeListener> listeners = new ArrayList<>();
    private boolean b1, b2;

    public MyClass() {
    }

    public boolean isB1() {
        return b1;
    }

    public void setB1(boolean b1) {
        boolean oldValue = this.b1;
        this.b1 = b1;
        firePropertyChange("b1", oldValue, b1);
    }

    public boolean isB2() {
        return b2;
    }

    public void setB2(boolean b2) {
        boolean oldValue = this.b2;
        this.b2 = b2;
        firePropertyChange("b2", oldValue, b2);
    }

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    private void firePropertyChange(String property, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
        for (PropertyChangeListener l : listeners) {
            l.propertyChange(new PropertyChangeEvent(this, property, oldValue, newValue));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Main method for tests.
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass m = new MyClass();

        m.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) {
                String changedProperty = e.getPropertyName();
                System.out.println("Changed property: " + changedProperty);
                System.out.println("New value: " + e.getNewValue());
                System.out.println("Old value: " + e.getOldValue());
                System.out.println();
            }
        });

        m.setB1(true);
        m.setB2(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions for your problem

1. Using plain Java, in that case, you shall add listeners to your bean (by yourself) and then invoke the listener methods on the setter method (again by yourself), and make the variable **private**, so it can only be modified by your setter method.
2. The second solution is using a pure AOP framework (I know AspectJ can do this), which can intercept modification of your variable, and then call your listener using an aspect. I shall mention that using @AspectJ (annotation support of AspectJ), your aspects would be pure Java classes, and there is no need to an AspectJ support IDE.

Comment: For more information on first solution look at JavaBeans Specification and samples.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Observer design pattern.
Just like this：

```
 public interface Listener
  {
      public void handle(Object o) ;
  }

  public class PropertiesChangeListener
  {
      public void handle(Object o) {
        //DO SOMETHING...
      }
  }
  
  public class Bean {
      private boolean flag;
      private List<Listener> listeners = new ArrayList<Listener>();

      public setFlag(boolean flag) {
        this.flag = flag;
        if (listeners.size() > 0 ) {
            for (Listener l : this.listeners ) {
                l.handle(flag); //invoke 
            }
        }
      }

      public registerListener(Listener listener) {
        this.listeners.add(listener);
      }

      //..... other fields and methods

  }

  public class Main{

      public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bean bean  = new Bean();
        bean.registerListener(new PropertiesChangeListener());
        bean.setFlag(true); //handler method will be invoked..
      }
  }
```